# Notification Hub Delivery failure C#

Tags: c#, azure, push, azure-notificationhub, azure-servicebus-queues

I have two notification hub clients (nodejs and C#), both used for pushing messages into a hub.

The Node client sends perfectly fine, yet the C# client completes with **no** message being sent.

Below are the snippets for the used in each client.

**C#**

```
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("<Connection String>", "<Hub Name>");
var notice = @"{'aps':{'alert':'Notification Hub test notification'}}";
var result = await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(notice, "<tag>");
Console.WriteLine(result.State);
```

**NodeJS**

```
var azure = require('azure');
var notificationHubService = azure.createNotificationHubService('<Hub Name>','<Connection String>')
var notice = "{'aps':{'alert':'Notification Hub test notification'}}"
notificationHubService.apns.send("<tag>", notice, function(error, res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

Both work fine when sending Android notifications and messages sent directly from the Azure portal Test feature are fine.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Duncan,

I think the issue is because your payload is malformed as you are using single quotes. Try the following:

```
var notice = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Notification Hub test notification\"}}";
```

Comment: I checked this and the payload is valid, the state on the result is "Enqueued". If i purposefully malform the payload i get "(400) Bad Request. The supplied notification payload is invalid".

Comment: @Duncan Once the notification sent, is the registration of your device dropped?

Comment: Nope the registration on the notification hub is still there and I can still push from the node client.

Comment: You were correct but your message structure was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `EnableTestSend` feature and look at the `NotificationOutcome` property for the detailed error message. This will send a test send message to 10 devices.

```
bool enableTestSend = true;
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(connString, hubName, enableTestSend);

var outcome = await hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(toast);
Console.WriteLine(outcome.State);

foreach (RegistrationResult result in outcome.Results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.ApplicationPlatform + "\n" + result.RegistrationId + "\n" + result.Outcome);
}
```

Comment: I've run the the hub with the test flag and there is no difference in the outcome. The state after sending is "Enqueued" but it doesn't get delivered.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR - No `''` (single quotes) allowed! Payload must containt `alert` key**

Not a very exciting solution but...

- If the notification payload contains single quotes even in a string literal the Notification hub will en-queue it without a malformed exception but when it reaches the APNS it will not be delivered as the payload is invalid according to them.
- If the notification payload doesn't have `alert` key present it will also be en-queued but not delivered by the APNS

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in my colleagues answers, you need to use double quotes in C# as a first step.

**Second, you also need to escape the json characters:**
Your payload should look like this:

```
var notice = "{{\"aps\":{{\"alert\":\"Notification Hub test notification\"}}}}";
```

Basically you escape the json braces { } by adding additional ones {{ }}.

This will send a valid json payload to the SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync() method. The payload now sent looks like this:

{"aps":{"alert":"Notification Hub test notification"}} (which is the correct notification format on iOS)

Here are the [valid json payloads for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) from the Apple Developer webpage.

You could always test if the json you are sending is a valid notification payload by using the 'Test Send' functionality in the Azure Notification Hub you are using.